# ws02 dataservice use parameter IN ORACLE_REF_CURSOR

Tags: oracle, cursor, wso2, ref, dataservice

I use WSO2 DataService for my web services. How can declare a parameter with:

- parameter IN
- type ORACLE_REF_CURSOR

I do not have any problem with OUT parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link at [1] to view how to work with ref cursors oracle.

[1]. http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/use-oracle-ref-cursors-wso2-data-services-server

Thank You,
Dharshana.